# unable to execute instructions after the post request, despite not getting any errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have an async function, the gets called on a button click, I want to execute some instructions after the post req, but unable to.

```
async function createPost() {
    try {
      await axios.post("http://localhost:3001/post", {
        content: postContent,
      });

      console.log("here:");
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.log("error: ", error.message);
    }
  }

   <button
          onClick={(e) => {
            // dispatch(setPosts([{ content: "hi", likes: 2 }]));

            createPost();
            // getPosts();
          }}
          className="absolute right-2 text-white bottom-2 bg-[#359BF0] px-5 py-2 rounded-full"
        >
          Post
    </button>
```

Backend:

```
app.post("/post", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    const createPost = await PostModel({
      content: req.body.content,
    });

    createPost.save();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error.message);
  }
});
```

I'm not getting any errors, and the post req is executed successfully, but for some reason the console.log("here") that comes after it does not.

Comment: Sounds like the promise returned by `axios.post()` never settles (ie: rejects or resolves). Can you maybe share the logic for your server where you're handling the `/post` route? Are you sure your server is sending a response back to the client?

Comment: @NickParsons The post request succeeds in saving the content to my db, and I don't get any errors: here is the back end: "Added to post"

Comment: Yep, but you never send a response back to the client to tell it that the server has done what it requested, you can do that with `res.end()` or `res.json()` for example

Comment: @NickParsons

Yup, no idea how I missed that. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are performing the logic in the backend but you never let the client know when the request is finished.

You need to  send a response back to the client like that after everything is finished

```js
app.post("/post", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);

  try {
    const createPost = await PostModel({
      content: req.body.content,
    });

    createPost.save();
   res.json({message: 'success'})
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error.message);
res.status(500).json({message: error.message})
  }
```

The reason is that the client is waiting for a response to terminate the call. If you don't send any response back the client is going to wait until a timeout error is raised